# Is it easier to obtain Spanish residency and work permit if my parents are Spanish residents?

Tags: eu, residency, spain

I'm a Russian citizen. My parents have Spanish residency via "Golden Visa", which you get i.e. for investment in real estate. Many countries offer less strict requirements and faster proceeding for family based immigration. Suppose that I'm interested in a permanent residency and work permit: Am I eligible for any immigration benefits or are there no advantages in comparison with people who have no connection to Spain at all?

Comment: Are you an adult?  Are your parents sufficiently old that they need you to look after them?  I *think* that if the answer to both these is "no", then the family connection is no help.

Comment: @MartinBonner, I'm an adult and my parents aren't very old, so it seems that there is no difference. Thanks for comment.